# How to take user inputs for Array through the parameter of the main function?

Tags: java

I have this:

```
class test {

    void main(int a[]) {

    }
}
```

What I basically want, is to get elements for my array this way, is it possible?

**Update:**

Okay, so many of you say that main can only take a string array, so here's the next problem:

```
class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Now when I enter a number there at the method call, it gives me an error:

> incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.String[]

**Update 2:** Alright, so I wasn't quoting them. XD

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. `main` **must** be `public static` and it **must** take a `String[]` as arguments. Or, it isn't a ***valid*** Java [entry point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#Java).

Comment: what language are you coding, i can't tell from the syntax.

Comment: is that so @JavaPilgrim

Comment: @JavaPilgrim The number you enter is command line? `main` should not be called by other way.

Comment: @JavaPilgrim now i can see your updated code, it looks like java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. The one correct signature of the `main` method is `main(String[] args)` (or `main(String... args)`). Also the method has to be `public static`. But you may try to convert this `String[]` array to `int[]`:

```
 int[] ints = new int[args.length];
 for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) ints[i] = Integer.valueof(args[i]);
```

Or Java 8 way:

```
 int[] ints = Arrays.stream(args).mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

`main`function must accept String array in Java, because command line parameter is a String array. Actually, C++/C also be same as Java.Just like this:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){} //C++/C
```

and

```
void main(String[] a){} // Java
```

Comment: what does C++/C do here? the question is about java

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Sorry, my expression is unclear, I have edited that again.